# After Nuxt build api returns 404

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, koa, nuxt.js, koa2

I'm having this weird issue and I seriously need your help. In development my code works perfectly fine but after doing nuxt build and all the apis are returning 404 error. Please help

When I'm building the api and running it, it works. In development api and nuxt both works but building nuxt and the api, doesn't work.

Following are my configuration

Server configuration

```
import convert from 'koa-convert';
import cors from 'kcors';
import bodyParser from 'koa-body';
import session from 'koa-session';
import helmet from 'koa-helmet';
import config from 'config';
import serve from 'koa-static';
import mount from 'koa-mount';

import { cModules, cMiddleware } from '../app';
import { catchErr, statusMessage } from './errorConfig';
import nuxtConfig from './nuxtConfig';

function baseConfig(app, io) {
  app.keys = config.get('secret');
  app.proxy = true;

  app.use(mount('/static', serve(config.get('paths.static'))));

  app.use(convert.compose(
    catchErr,
    cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: true
    }),
    bodyParser({
      multipart: true,
      formLimit: '200mb'
    }),
    session({
      maxAge: 21600000
    }, app),
    helmet(),
    statusMessage
  ));

  cModules(app, io);
  app.use(cMiddleware());

  if (config.get('nuxtBuild')) {
    nuxtConfig(app);
  }
}

export default baseConfig;
```

And my Nuxt

```
import { Nuxt, Builder } from 'nuxt';
import koaConnect from 'koa-connect';
import isDev from 'isdev';
import config from '../../../nuxt.config';

async function nuxtConfig(app) {
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

  if (isDev) {
    await new Builder(nuxt).build();
  }
  const nuxtRender = koaConnect(nuxt.render);

  app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    await next();
    ctx.status = 200;
    ctx.req.session = ctx.session;
    await nuxtRender(ctx);
  });
}

export default nuxtConfig;
```

Comment: What is the traceback when you do `nuxt build` / `nuxt start` ?